# How to process big data

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

I have about ~ 1T of data from tracking user behaviour (AddToCart, Pageview, Purchased ....) and saved to Cassandra. 
Now i have to analyze this data for getting revenue, number of request .... and build recommendation system

As i researched, Some candidates are:

For recommendation:

```
+ Spark on HDFS or HBase  (Do i have to migrate data from cassandra to HDFS)

+ Spark on Cassandra
```

For query:

```
+ Cassandra + Hive
+ Hbase + Hive
```

In depth, i dont completely understand about processing bigdata

Do you have any suggestion about technology for me to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Use an SQL database.

Comment: This is far too broad, and as you can see from the first comment, invites controversy rather than fact-based answers.